# webview android app issues

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

[image: this shows the header exceeds the width of the] [image: this part should be invisible and pop when i click a button]i'm a web developer so i don't have a large knowledge with android apps, but i have found a project on github to make a simple webview app to show a website i have created which is fully responsible and work fine with all browsers on desktop and android phones, when i run the app in android studio it works great and everything run smoothly in many emulators, but when i install the apk on physical phone some problems show include taking larger width than the device and some containers which displayed 'none' shows at the bottom of the page and there are many issues with the proportions of the pages, i hope someone can help me to locate the problem or guide me to where i can search for it and find it by myself

this is the [url](https://github.com/slymax/webview) to the github project

thank you very much

Comment: Can you maybe post a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: @JohanDewaal i have updated the post

Answer (score 1):

I see, I think just adding this code to your MainActivity will do the trick!

```
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

maybe try this too:

```
WebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```

put the above code below :

```
 mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

hope this helps :D and please tell me if it does!

Comment: this fix most of the issues thank you very much :) the only thing left is that the header still takes larger width in some pages :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. . . I **might** have another thing you can try :)

Comment: i have noted something, when the page is loading it looks normal but once it's done the width of header increased immediately, i think because it takes the landscape width after loading the page even when the phone in portrait position so when i flip the phone everything looks fine
thank you again for your help :)

Comment: Sure no problem! I love helping people  and I hope you get the app to work completely like you want it 